# Drop down menu doesnt work

Tags: php, html, css

My Drop down menu to choose a date does not work unless I hold down left click on my mouse.
Only the year drop down works correctly but the month and days only work if you hold your mouse button down.

Here is the website it is on:  www.cipslimoshuttle.com/tickets

Here is the code:

```
<label>
                            Date of travel:
                            <select name="ticketYear">
                                <?php
                                    $i = date('Y');
                                    while($i <= date('Y')+5){
                                        ?>
                                <option <?php if(date('Y') == $i) echo 'selected' ?> value="<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i ?></option>
                                        <?php
                                        $i++;
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                            <select name="ticketDay">
                                <?php
                                    $i = 1;
                                    while($i <= 31){
                                        ?>
                                        <option <?php if(date('j') == $i) echo 'selected' ?> value="<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i ?></option>
                                        <?php
                                        $i++;
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                            <select name="ticketMonth">
                                <?php
                                    $months = array(
                                        '01-January',
                                        '02-February',
                                        '03-March',
                                        '04-April',
                                        '05-May',
                                        '06-June',
                                        '07-July',
                                        '08-August',
                                        '09-September',
                                        '10-October',
                                        '11-November',
                                        '12-December'
                                        );
                                    foreach($months as $month) {
                                        $month = explode('-',$month);
                                        ?>
                                        <option <?php if(date('m') == $month[0]) echo 'selected' ?> value="<?php echo $month[0] ?>"><?php echo $month[1] ?></option>
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </label>
```

Comment: Its a browser issue its working fine in chrome

Comment: Can you paste the resulting HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your label tag You need to end before the select box.Check this it will work

```
<label>
                                Date of travel: </label>
                                <select name="ticketYear">
                                    <?php
                                        $i = date('Y');
                                        while($i <= date('Y')+5){
                                            ?>
                                    <option <?php if(date('Y') == $i) echo 'selected' ?> value="<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i ?></option>
                                            <?php
                                            $i++;
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                                <select name="ticketDay">
                                    <?php
                                        $i = 1;
                                        while($i <= 31){
                                            ?>
                                            <option <?php if(date('j') == $i) echo 'selected' ?> value="<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i ?></option>
                                            <?php
                                            $i++;
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                                <select name="ticketMonth">
                                    <?php
                                        $months = array(
                                            '01-January',
                                            '02-February',
                                            '03-March',
                                            '04-April',
                                            '05-May',
                                            '06-June',
                                            '07-July',
                                            '08-August',
                                            '09-September',
                                            '10-October',
                                            '11-November',
                                            '12-December'
                                            );
                                        foreach($months as $month) {
                                            $month = explode('-',$month);
                                            ?>
                                            <option <?php if(date('m') == $month[0]) echo 'selected' ?> value="<?php echo $month[0] ?>"><?php echo $month[1] ?></option>
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
```